# remove lines with stream editor

Tags: awk, sed

I have a problem removing some lines from text.

this is the output from the file  :

```
# SHA512 HASH
96896c1b0b52047fac3cdcfea7b15c3eca7fcc53ee3294000493d4421df61e7947cdcaed783edc95e8ba51fbed164f383fc09afdb73587e590e08eef08086a4d  stage3-amd64-nomultilib-20160310.tar.bz2
# WHIRLPOOL HASH
e5e15b81753c6f1dd1886c2567b0012bfd822746d8ddce32ddf6e41f64074b4cb9c49dce787ea4cb160ce1234e0a8ba1d3a66b3904a2fb5500c435dd0fc69fea  stage3-amd64-nomultilib-20160310.tar.bz2
# SHA512 HASH
35735f8c7533bf6cda384a015e3eaac61b89e832f181c49332b04c07cbd3dfe7a61d5c5dce7c1e4155880b2a4e690839efcd914f04523b2a0e1e903749be6192  stage3-amd64-nomultilib-20160310.tar.bz2.CONTENTS# WHIRLPOOL HASH
c04c4d0f677c0e035262632e4fd03d71a786019b94a0ca0565a6c1af51a9103315e3da030d7c0f071ee729543f9b5d591757e43fad6ee66ff5dff88968eb8d2c  stage3-amd64-nomultilib-20160310.tar.bz2.CONTENTS
```

my mission is to Remove lines verifying .CONTENTS, remove WHIRLPOOL hashes, and verify the remaining SHA-512 digest ,as i understand i need to put # in every line i need to delete,i think it can be done using sed or awk.

the desired output is :

```
# SHA512 HASH
96896c1b0b52047fac3cdcfea7b15c3eca7fcc53ee3294000493d4421df61e7947cdcaed783edc95e8ba51fbed164f383fc09afdb73587e590e08eef08086a4d  stage3-amd64-nomultilib-20160310.tar.bz2
# WHIRLPOOL HASH
#e5e15b81753c6f1dd1886c2567b0012bfd822746d8ddce32ddf6e41f64074b4cb9c49dce787ea4cb160ce1234e0a8ba1d3a66b3904a2fb5500c435dd0fc69fea  stage3-amd64-nomultilib-20160310.tar.bz2
# SHA512 HASH
#35735f8c7533bf6cda384a015e3eaac61b89e832f181c49332b04c07cbd3dfe7a61d5c5dce7c1e4155880b2a4e690839efcd914f04523b2a0e1e903749be6192  stage3-amd64-nomultilib-20160310.tar.bz2.CONTENTS# WHIRLPOOL HASH
c04c4d0f677c0e035262632e4fd03d71a786019b94a0ca0565a6c1af51a9103315e3da030d7c0f071ee729543f9b5d591757e43fad6ee66ff5dff88968eb8d2c  stage3-amd64-nomultilib-20160310.tar.bz2.CONTENTS
```

Thank you

Comment: Can you include the desired output?

Comment: Where is this related to GnuPG? Anyway, this does not seem like an actual development question, and is more about general computer usage which is off-topic on Stack Overflow.

Comment: after i use gpg on the DIGESTS.asc file ,a new file DIGESTS is generated and what i posted is the content of it.

Comment: Are you sure that's your exact input? Is `# WHIRLPOOL HASH` really at the end of the second last line, and not on a line of its own?

Comment: it's on a line of its own

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to do this in `sed` or `awk` but I whipped up a quick and dirty Python script for you to try. This script will NOT change your original file. It will create final.yourfilename, which you can then rename. You'll have to adjust the script for your use case.

**tests.py** (keep it in the same directory as your file with SHAs)

```
file = 'tests.txt' # this is your original file. Replace it with your filename
phrase_of_interest = '.CONTENTS' # we want to look for this phrase
shas_to_comment = [] # list holds information after .CONTENTS like # WHIRLPOOL HASH

# first pass - comment out the line containing .CONTENTS# WHATEVER and remember # WHATEVER in list
with open('tmp.' + file, 'w') as n:
    with open(file, 'r') as f:
        for line in f:          
            if phrase_of_interest + '#' in line:
                n.write('#' + line)
                shas_to_comment.append(line[line.index(phrase_of_interest + '#'):].replace(phrase_of_interest, '').strip())
                #                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
                #                           finds position of .CONTENTS#
                #                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
                #                          extracts .CONTENTS# WHATEVER
                #                                                                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
                #                                                                  removes .CONTENTS, leaving behind #WHATEVER
                # strip(), in this case, is intended to remove \n
                # shas_to_comment will contain # WHATEVER1, # WHATEVER2 etc.
            else:
                n.write(line)

# second pass - now that we know which shas to comment, when we find a comment like # WHIRLPOOL HASH,
# we will set comment_next_line flag to true. The next line will be commented out and comment_next_line flag will be reset
comment_next_line = False
with open('final.' + file, 'w') as n:
    with open('tmp.' + file, 'r') as f:
        for line in f:
            if comment_next_line:
                n.write('#' + line)
            else:
                n.write(line)

            comment_next_line = line.strip() in shas_to_comment

# your final result will be in final.tests.txt file
```

With your file, the result will be:

`python tests.py`

```
# SHA512 HASH
96896c1b0b52047fac3cdcfea7b15c3eca7fcc53ee3294000493d4421df61e7947cdcaed783edc95e8ba51fbed164f383fc09afdb73587e590e08eef08086a4d  stage3-amd64-nomultilib-20160310.tar.bz2
# WHIRLPOOL HASH
#e5e15b81753c6f1dd1886c2567b0012bfd822746d8ddce32ddf6e41f64074b4cb9c49dce787ea4cb160ce1234e0a8ba1d3a66b3904a2fb5500c435dd0fc69fea  stage3-amd64-nomultilib-20160310.tar.bz2
# SHA512 HASH
#35735f8c7533bf6cda384a015e3eaac61b89e832f181c49332b04c07cbd3dfe7a61d5c5dce7c1e4155880b2a4e690839efcd914f04523b2a0e1e903749be6192  stage3-amd64-nomultilib-20160310.tar.bz2.CONTENTS# WHIRLPOOL HASH
c04c4d0f677c0e035262632e4fd03d71a786019b94a0ca0565a6c1af51a9103315e3da030d7c0f071ee729543f9b5d591757e43fad6ee66ff5dff88968eb8d2c  stage3-amd64-nomultilib-20160310.tar.bz2.CONTENTS
```

**Using bash script**

**tests.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash

file='tests.txt' # this is your original file
shas_to_comment=()

while read -r line; do
    if [[ $line == *".CONTENTS#"* ]]; then
        hashline=$(echo $line | awk -F '.CONTENTS' '{print $2}')
        shas_to_comment=("${shas_to_comment[@]}" "$hashline")
    fi
done < $file

comment_next_line=0
while read -r line; do
    for item in "${shas_to_comment[@]}"; do

        if [[ $comment_next_line -eq 1 ]]; then
            echo "#$line"
            comment_next_line=0
            continue
        fi

        if [[ $line == *".CONTENTS${item}"* ]]; then
            echo "#$line"
            continue
        fi

        echo $line

        if [[ $line == $item ]]; then
            comment_next_line=1
        fi

    done
done < $file
```

With your file, the result will be:

`bash tests.sh`

```
# SHA512 HASH
96896c1b0b52047fac3cdcfea7b15c3eca7fcc53ee3294000493d4421df61e7947cdcaed783edc95e8ba51fbed164f383fc09afdb73587e590e08eef08086a4d stage3-amd64-nomultilib-20160310.tar.bz2
# WHIRLPOOL HASH
#e5e15b81753c6f1dd1886c2567b0012bfd822746d8ddce32ddf6e41f64074b4cb9c49dce787ea4cb160ce1234e0a8ba1d3a66b3904a2fb5500c435dd0fc69fea  stage3-amd64-nomultilib-20160310.tar.bz2
# SHA512 HASH
#35735f8c7533bf6cda384a015e3eaac61b89e832f181c49332b04c07cbd3dfe7a61d5c5dce7c1e4155880b2a4e690839efcd914f04523b2a0e1e903749be6192  stage3-amd64-nomultilib-20160310.tar.bz2.CONTENTS# WHIRLPOOL HASH
c04c4d0f677c0e035262632e4fd03d71a786019b94a0ca0565a6c1af51a9103315e3da030d7c0f071ee729543f9b5d591757e43fad6ee66ff5dff88968eb8d2c stage3-amd64-nomultilib-20160310.tar.bz2.CONTENTS
```

Comment: i need to do it only with shell script.

Comment: Are there any other constraints - e.g. that you only need to use awk or sed or cut or such?

Comment: @Maximtoyberman - added a script that I hope works well for you. You may have to tweak it for your specific use case

Comment: @Maximtoyberman - did this answer help you? If so, please feel free to put a closure to your question by marking it accepted. Feel free to wait for more answers also